# Python design patterns: Nested Abstract Classes

Tags: python-3.x, oop, design-patterns, abstract-class

In the following example code, I want every `car` object to be composed of `brake_system` and `engine_system` objects, which are stored as attributes on the car.

To implement this, I've defined `Car`, `BreakSystem` and `EngineSystem` as abstract classes. Every subclass of `Car` is required to define its respective `BreakSystem` and `EngineSystem` subclasses as class attributes.

Are there any potential problems with this approach? Or are there other design patterns better suited to handle nested abstractions?

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Car(ABC):
    """
    every car object should have an Engine object and a BrakeSystem object
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.engine_system = self._engine_type()
        self.brake_system = self._brake_type()

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def _engine_type(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def _brake_type(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class EngineSystem(ABC):
    pass

class BrakeSystem(ABC):
    pass


class FooBrakeSystem(BrakeSystem):
    pass

class FooEngineSystem(EngineSystem):
    pass

class FooCar(Car):
    _engine_type = FooEngineSystem
    _brake_type = FooBrakeSystem

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = FooCar()
```

Comment: There are no problems per-se with this, but why use ABCs at all here? Why should the ABC, which commonly are used to document a public API, be concerned with an implementation detail of the car? Are the engine and brake types public API information?

Comment: Isn't this a typical use case for ABCs? We only want the `car` class to be initialized through its subclasses, so we make it an ABC. I haven't written public APIs, but I often still use ABCs to organize hierarchies of related classes.

Comment: No, it’s not a typical use. ABCs are more commonly used to help third-party developers understand what they must provide when implementing a specific “protocol”, a set of methods on a class that together define a pattern of behaviour. Take a look at the `collections.abc` module for definitions of Python container behaviours. It doesn’t matter what the internal implementation of a `Mapping` class might be, as long as it implements the abstract methods of the ABC other code can rely on it to have all the right methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I want every car object to be composed of `brake_system` and `engine_system` objects

You have abstract classes for the systems

```
class EngineSystem(ABC):
    pass

class BrakeSystem(ABC):
    pass
```

A car has to consists of two systems:

```
class Car:

    def __init__(self, engine: EngineSystem, brake: BrakeSystem):
        self._engine_system = engine
        self._brake_system = brake

    @property
    def engine_type(self) -> EngineSystem:
        return self._engine_system

    @property
    def brake_type(self) -> BrakeSystem:
        return self._engine_system
```

And now, if you need to create a specific car

```
tesla = Car(ElectroEngine(), Disks())

# or even 
class Tesla(Car):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(ElectroEngine(), Disks())

tesla = Tesla()
```

This approach allows you to create a `car` as a composition of its systems.

Comment: Minor comment: in the def brake_type I believe return should be self._brake_system (?)

Answer (score 0):

I'm beginner in python.

Answering your question on the basis of OO concepts, It is perfectly fine to have nested abstraction to enforce the implementer to must define what outer class encapsulates. And I do not see any potential problem in this structure.

In your example `Car` has `BreakSystem` and `EngineSystem` makes perfect sense when one has to simulate real word entities as software and at the same time all are very generic so having them as abstract is acceptable and letting the implementer to define the details in concrete classes.

This can also be simulated if you have composition, **Example** one can have Building and Room as abstract types (where Building is composed of Rooms), and using Flat/House this can be realized where House/Flat has Rooms like DiningRoom and/or DrawingRoom etc.